# Can't start login service or avahi-daemon service, hangs

Tags: retropie

Using Pi 3 Model B with Noobs dual booting Raspian/RetroPie. boots into Raspian fine but I get this when trying to load RetroPie. Not sure where to look or how to fix this issue? Loaded up Raspian and ran and update/upgrade adn then restarted to boot into RetroPi and this is all I get.

My only option is a ctrl+alt+del that goes straight to a reboot.

[image: error message]

Comment: It's preferrable not to show pictures. Try typing out in your post what you see on the screen.